# Soccer Dads and Hockey Moms

Tags: meaning, idioms

When I was participating in a competition, a rule said no hockey moms and soccer dads are allowed. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, roughly, "No parents of kids who play in organized youth sports."

You can read about how the term *soccer mom* vaulted into popularity on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soccer_mom). (The term has other variants as well, such as *hockey mom, soccer dad, cheerleader mom*, etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what: "No parents of kids who play in organized youth sports." means.

Comment: If you have children (roughly between the ages of 9 and 14) and those kids play sports (such as ice hockey or soccer), and you bring those kids back and forth to practices and games (probably in a minivan), then you are not allowed. I can't give you any more information than that, because you've haven't indicated what kind of competition you were participating in, what this "rule" was related to, or what it means by "allowed" (allowed to attend? allowed to compete?)

Comment: Sorry, it was a robotics competition, not related to sports. On the rules for the competition, it just said: Hockey Moms and Soccer Dads are not allowed. It is a competition for middle school kids.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like they don't want the parents around while the kids are competing. I think it was probably meant to be a humorous reference.